# How to use an aggregate function over all groups in SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

if i use sum(), it sums over one group, but i want something like sum()/sum_over_all_groups(), is there a way we can do it without first summing over all groups in a separate query and then putting the resulting number in place of sum_over_all_groups()?

Comment: Your question is not clear. Can you show a sample data and the expected result?

Comment: using a join. But if you don't show us a table structure and an example of expected result we cannot help (i guess you are trying to calculate the weight of each group on the total)

Comment: sorry, I'll try to put all the data and the specific example i'm working on as soon as i get time,

Comment: Using an uncorrelated sub-select?

Comment: That's called windowing function on RDBMS that supports it. MySQL doesn't support it. If you are using MySQL, you reallly have no option but to join your grouping query to another query (grand total) result. Matteo's answer is correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can join the whole sum:

```
SELECT SUM(field_to_sum) / total_sum
FROM your_table t
CROSS JOIN (
    SELECT SUM(field_to_sum) total_sum
    FROM your_table
) d
GROUP BY t.field_to_group
```

Comment: `"is there a way we can do it without first summing over all groups in a separate query" `

Comment: shouldn't there be a "on" after joining ? because it says 'incorrect syntax near keyword "group"'

Comment: @brenners1302 in fact that is **not** a *separate* query, it is all in the same one